# Warning on direct access to struct member returned by function

Tags: c, function, struct

is there a GCC warning flag that prints a warning if a function returns a struct and member of this struct is accessed directly (*function().x*).

Thanks,
Tom

```
struct my  my_function();

int main(){
   int a;
   struct my b;
   int c;

   // There shold be a warning:
   a = my_function().member1;

   // This is OK:
   b = my_function();
   c = b.member1;
}
```

Comment: Here is the related gcc page: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html
You can try defining the function with `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`, but I am not sure if it helps, because you are not ignoring the return value.

Comment: `// There shold be a warning:` - Because... ? Your question would be better served if you also explained *why* you feel such a warning is warranted.

Comment: "why you feel such a warning is warranted": It's about internal coding guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such warning in GCC.

You can test for warning options in GCC by compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` to turn on all warning options. If such a warning exists, this will reveal it and show its name. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/RC3RjX) shows there is no warning for this.